# merging SQL statements and how can it affect processing time

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume I have the following tables:

```
items table
item_id|view_count

item_views table
view_id|item_id|ip_address|last_view
```

What I would like to do is:
If last view of item with given item_id by given ip_address was 1+ hour ago I would like to increment view_count of item in items table. And as a result get the view count of item. How I will do it normally:

```
q = SELECT count(*) FROM item_views WHERE item_id='item_id' AND ip_address='some_ip' AND last_view < current_time-60*60

if(q==1) then q = UPDATE items SET view_count = view_count+1 WHERE item_id='item_id'

//and finally get view_count of item
q = SELECT view_count FROM items WHERE item_id='item_id'
```

Here I used 3 SQL queries. How can I merge it into one SQL query? And how can it affect the processing time? Will it be faster or slower than previous method?

Comment: Are you trying to optimize the performance of the queries or reduce them to a single statement?

Comment: optimize the performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your logic is correct for what you describe that you want.  The query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM item_views
WHERE item_id='item_id' AND
      ip_address='some_ip' AND
      last_view < current_time-60*60
```

is counting the number of views longer ago than your time frame.  I think you want:

```
      last_view > current_time-60*60
```

and then have `if q = 0` on the next line.

MySQL is pretty good with the performance of `not exists`, so the following should work well:
    update items
        set view_count = view_count+1
        WHERE item_id='item_id' and
              not exists (select 1 
                          from item_views
                          where item_id='item_id' AND
                                ip_address='some_ip' AND
                                last_view > current_time-60*60
                         )

It will work much better with an index on `item_views(item_id, ip_address, last_view)` and an index on `item(item_id)`.

In MySQL scripting, you could then write:

```
. . .
     set view_count = (@q := view_count+1)
. . .
```

This would also give you the variable you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
update target
    set target.view_count = target.view_count + 1
from items target
inner join (
    select item_id
    from item_views
    where item_id = 'item_id'
        and ip_address = 'some_ip'
        and last_view < current_time - 60*60
    ) ref
    on ref.item_id = target.item_id;
```

You can only combine the update statement with the condition using a join as in the above example; but you'll still need a separate select statement.
It may be slower on very large set and/or unindexed table.